# .NET ObjectListView Control - How to add multiple icons to single cell with a click event for each icon

Tags: c#, .net, objectlistview

I'm using the latest version of ObjectListView [Version 2.9.1 (2016-05-05)]

URL: http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/

I'd like to implement the functionality that's shown in the screenshot below:

[image: Flags Column]

A "flags" column which contains clickable icons (some could be disabled).

It appears that ObjectListView control supports adding a single button within a cell. However, I don't see anything pertaining to adding multiple buttons/clickable icons within a single cell as shown in the screenshot.

**NOTE**: The screenshot is just a visual of what I want. It's NOT an actual screenshot of the ObjectListView control.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will find your answer here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16009/A-Much-Easier-to-Use-ListView-2

**4.5 (Owner) Drawn and quartered**

```
<span id="ArticleContent"><span>columnOD.RendererDelegate = delegate(DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs e,
    Graphics g, Rectangle r, Object rowObject) {
    g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), r);
    g.DrawString(((Person)rowObject).Name, objectListView1.Font,
        new SolidBrush(Color.Black), r.X, r.Y);
}</span></span>
```

To use any of these renderers or your own custom subclass, you assign an instance of them to a column's **Renderer** property, like this:

```
<span id="ArticleContent"><span>colCookingSkill.Renderer = new MultiImageRenderer(Resource1.star16, 5, 0, 40);</span></span>
```

**Im pritty sure you will find your asnwer there!**

Comment: Thanks Anton! I'll take a look and report back if I find a solution!